# Can my deck footers be this high above ground?

Tags: deck

I need some advice on concrete footings.

I am expanding my existing deck by 10 feet and I need to pour 4 concrete footings for the 6x6 #2 Southern pine posts I plan to set. Here is a screenshot of the side profile.

[image: Side profile]

Here is a screenshot of the footer detail. I plan to pour them over 1/2" rebar in the tube form. The bottom 4" will be pea gravel. The top of the footer will be level with the top of my slab.

[image: Footer detail]

My question...I will have 24" of reinforced concrete below existing grade. Will having 18" above grade be a problem? I am doing that so that I can use 8-foot posts.

Comment: What is your local frost level?  The footer will need to go down that low at least.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to bury at least 1/3 of a post in the ground. You're burying more than 1/2, so you should be good to go. Just make sure you're below the frost line or you're wasting time & money...

Comment: I am in deep South Louisiana. We don't have a frost line lol.

Comment: Could I reduce the depth to 12" below grade?

Comment: You tagged it with [tag:code-compliance], what does your local AHJ have to say? They're the ones who will be inspecting and will have the final say.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions of local code compliance are explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I didn't mean to post it with a code compliance tag

Comment: What kind of soil do you have? If it's expansive, I wouldn't like it for stability reasons. Otherwise I'm still probably not fond of it for stability reasons. Your post to concrete interface is effectively a hinge unless you're paying big bucks for a moment resisting post connection (or embedding the post in the concrete). The soil strength beside the foundation is critical to resist a buckling mode with the hinge moving horizontally. The soil braces the foundation if there's no knee bracing or similar up at the deck elevation.

Comment: It looks like you already might be familiar, but have you seen [IRC R507.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch05_SecR507.3)?

Comment: You should definitely swap the pea gravel for a base with some sharp corners. Even with good confinement from the sides, that pea gravel is a stability liability instead of the asset that it should be.

Comment: Our soil here is typical wetland-type soil, silty loam. The water table varies with season but is usually around 6 feet average depth below surface. Here are the post-to-concrete brackets (https://www.lowes.com/pd/Nuvo-Iron/5013302147). I just had a look at that code and need to study it a little more. The whole idea here is to prevent having to buy 10-foot 6x6 posts...save a little money using 8-footers.

Comment: Would a fine-grained sand be a better base?

Comment: The sand is probably okay. Theoretically it could be as bad as the pea gravel, but realistically I think it's typically more angular and better graded. If you're going by-the-book with "gravel" spec'ed, sand ain't gravel. Mixing the two could give you a better graded gravel and still pass as by-the-book. I assume this is stuff that you have laying around. If not, then just get an angular base.

Comment: No. Our soil isn't a clay. I don't think you'd hit a clay layer here until about 8 feet down. I do like the idea of mixing sand with gravel. There's no shortage of sand here. I can get sand cheap.

Comment: I'm surprised that the concrete plus form cost doesn't exceed the cost of an extra 2 ft of post. Again, though, I don't know what you have laying around. Begrudgingly, a silty loam sounds adequate, but I'm no geotech. My worry would be any soil that opens up a gap with its adjacent structure. That combined with the pea gravel sounds like a major stability issue.

Comment: If you have an inspector poking around, then the formal definition of gravel would require 50% of the sand/gravel mixture's material to be retained on a 5mm=1/5" screen. That's 50% by weight.

Comment: I don't want to put the posts in the ground or embed them in the concrete. Down here, that's a recipe for disaster when the posts start rotting out below the surface. I'd much rather be able to replace a post that's on top of a concrete footing. I do get what you're saying though. It might be worth comparing the cost of using the 10-foot posts and using shorter footings.

Comment: I totally understand keeping the posts out of the concrete. With a _little_ longer eave I might quibble with you. And check your posts against the code. You might get away with 4×4s. Compute an area by multiplying half the distance back to the existing deck (5', right?) times your largest post spacing walking into the page. For using the IRC table, multiply that area by 1.3 to get an effective tributary area that accounts for the additional load from your roof.